# jQueryUI autocomplete implementing search page replacement

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

On the ([now old](http://www.learningjquery.com/2010/06/autocomplete-migration-guide)) jQuery autocomplete plugin there was the functionality that if the user clicked on or pressed enter to select an autocompletion, they were taken to that page - i.e. they skipped the search results page. Details here: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete#Search_Page_Replacement

I'm using the new [jQueryUI Autocomplete Widget](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/), and am really struggling trying to figure out how to implement this feature.

Are there any jQuery gurus out there who know how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({
  select: function(event, ui) { 
     location.href = ui.item.url;
  }
});
```

http://jsbin.com/oliqu3/edit

Comment: To anyone reading remember to include a 'url' property for each object returned (i.e. output = [{ 'label': 'hello', 'url': '/random' }])